# What does this recursive function do

Tags: c, recursion

i am doing some exam prep and one of the question is to describe what the following piece of C code does.

```
int g(int *a, int b ,int c){
if(b==c) return a[b];
return g(a,b,(b+c)/2) + g(a,(b+c)/2+1 ,c);}
```

Cant seem to figure out the recursion, from my understanding the sum of the left hand
is sum of the series b+2^n/2*c  and sum of the series of right to be (2^n/2)*(b+c) where  n starts at 0. But there is no value for n that will make the series to be equal b or c respectively. Does that mean if the first if condition isn't meet it will continue on for infinity?

Comment: This looks obfuscated. Do you have access to a version with real variable names?

Comment: unfortunately not , the idea of the question was to figure out what it does and rewrite it with meaningful variable names and good programming practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `b < c`, `g()` returns the sum of the elements of the array `a[]` from index `b` to index `c` (both inclusive)

In other words,

```
g( a, b, c ) := 

int sum = 0;
for( int i = b; i <= c; ++i )
    sum += a[ i ];
return sum;
```

#### EDIT Proof Sketch

```
Assume c - b = n

(b + c)/2
= (c - b + 2b)/2
= (c - b)/2 + b
= b + n/2

Thus, g( a, b, (b + c)/2 ) + g( a, (b + c)/2 + 1, c )
= g( a, b, b + n/2 ) + g( a, b + n/2 + 1, c )
```

Comment: That really cleared it up, have you any advice on approaching similar questions. Thanks for your help